# Need way to determine whether function has void return type in VC6 and VC7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

The following C++ code compiles and runs correctly for GNU g++, LLVM and every other C++ compiler I threw at it except for Microsoft VC6 and VC7:

```
template<typename A, typename B> int HasVoidReturnType(A(*)(B)) { return 0; }
template<typename B> int HasVoidReturnType(void(*)(B)) { return 1; }
void f(double) {}
int foo() { return HasVoidReturnType(f); }
```

For VC6 and VC7, it fails to compile and gives the error:

```
f.cpp(4) : error C2667: 'HasVoidReturnType' : none of 2 overloads have a best conversion
    f.cpp(2): could be 'int HasVoidReturnType(void (__cdecl *)(B))'
    f.cpp(1): or       'int HasVoidReturnType(A (__cdecl *)(B))'
    while trying to match the argument list '(overloaded-function)'
f.cpp(4) : error C2668: 'HasVoidReturnType' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
    f.cpp(2): could be 'int HasVoidReturnType(void (__cdecl *)(B))'
    f.cpp(1): or       'int HasVoidReturnType(A (__cdecl *)(B))'
    while trying to match the argument list '(overloaded-function)'
```

Rather than arguing the merits of what compiler is right, how can I determine from a template function whether a function has a void return type using VC6 and VC7?

Answer (score 3):

Try this on for size

```
template<typename FuncPtrType>
struct DecomposeFuncPtr;

template<typename ReturnType, typename ArgType>
struct DecomposeFuncPtr<ReturnType(*)(ArgType)> {
  typedef ReturnType return_type;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_void {
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template<>
struct is_void<void> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template<typename T>
int HasVoidReturnType(T dontcare) {
  return is_void< typename DecomposeFuncPtr<T>::return_type >::value;
}
```

it should avoid the overloading that is confusing VC6/7.

Hrmm. Sorry I couldn't test it with VC6/7. I see to recall running into issues using function pointers with templates before in VC though. Since we know the A, B works for the function in your original, I wonder if something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_void {
  enum { value = 0 };
};

template<>
struct is_void<void> {
  enum { value = 1 };
};

template<typename A, typename B>
int HasVoidReturnType(A(*)(B)) {
  return is_void<A>::value;
}
```

would work.

Comment: VC7:
t.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'ReturnType' : undeclared identifier
...
t.cpp(15) : error C2913: explicit specialization; 'is_void is_void' is not a class template

Comment: Try  template<typename A, typename B> char (& HasVoidReturnType(A(*)(B)) )[is_void<A>::value + 1];  then sizeof(HasVoidReturnType(fun)) can tell you either 1 or 2 depending on whether it returns void. maybe that works with vc6 too? it would work at compile time :)

Comment: The last way is how I would have written it in the first place - but probably because I don't grok overload resolution compared to template specialization.

Answer (score 3):

As far as VC++ 6 is concerned, you are screwed, as it doesn't support partial template specialisation, which is what you need to solve this problem.

Comment: VC++ 6 can barely be called a "C++ compiler".

Comment: VC++ 7.0 also sucks.  VC++ 7.1, on the other hand, is a pretty decent C++ compiler.  The version numbering system here is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two templates, have you tried just using the first one and using template specialization to define the second?

Answer (score 0):

FYI this is compilable on C++ 2008 Express edition from Microsoft. (I would have liked to help but can't reproduce the problem on my compiler)